# Do the point collections on .NET charts have an upper limit?

Tags: c#, .net, charts

I'm new to the charting functions in .NET's `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` library. During my exploratory prototyping, I created a chart to which I can add random points, change the chart type, etc. But I noticed that every time I add more than 34998 points to the chart (regardless of which type of chart type I use), the entire chart disappears and is replaced with a big 'X'. No exception is thrown, and it doesn't appear to be a limitation of the point collection itself. (If I step through the code when adding the 34999th point, it gets added to the collecion just fine; but as soon as the chart gets repainted, it immediately gets replaced with the X).

I realize that this is a large number of points to have on a chart in the first place, and I plan to look at some decimation techniques to down-sample my input data. But I was just wondering if there is a hard limit at this number, and which module in the system is the actual constraint (dataset, drawing canvas, etc). I couldn't find any mention of it in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/Dd456769(v=vs.110).aspx). Does anyone know of such a limit?

Comment: I have charts with point counts in the 400,000+ (24 hours of data every 2 seconds for 15+ pieces of equipment) and while it slows down, it loads just fine.

Comment: The big red X is automatically drawn by Winforms when the Paint event handler of the control throws an exception.  The exception is swallowed, that's why it *looks* like there's no exception.  Easy to see in the Output window btw.  You'd use Debug > Exceptions > Thrown checkbox to have a better look.

Comment: @HansPassant- Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately Output window (set to "Show output from Debug") displays no messages. Also, in the Debug Exceptions dialog, I have checked every box under "Thrown" and "User-unhandled", yet the system does not break even after the red X appears. (I notice that there is a button to Add exceptions in that dialog; would you happen to know exactly which exception I might be looking for?)

Comment: @HansPassant- I'm getting closer: Under `Tools->Options->Debugging->General` I UN-checked "Enable Just My Code". The system now breaks with the exception, as you suggested. (While I was in there, I also noticed the setting "Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window" was checked (by default??) which explains why my Output window was empty.

Answer (score 2):

This line chart has 2 series with 1,000,000 points each:
[image]

and it takes 6 seconds to render. I guess the limit is just available memory. One common cause for the "Big Red X Of Doom" is if the points you're adding are outside the Axis's Minimum and Maximum values, in case you're manipulating those.